# "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error when publishing page

Tags: 2011, cme

I have the following problem when publishing pages, though the file system shows the published pages.

Any suggestions are welcome.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {9926D1CF-F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due
>   to the following error: 8007000e Not enough storage is available to
>   complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E
>   (E_OUTOFMEMORY)).
>
> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {9926D1CF-F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due to the following
>   error: 8007000e Not enough storage is available to complete this
>   operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY)).

**I have restarted the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application, but the issue continues and the COM+ application restarts every minute.**

Comment: Hello, Satyam and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange! :-) I edited the text to make your question and symptoms clearer. Let us know if this still matches your original intent.

Comment: Thanx Alvin for your effort.

Answer (score 5):

This means that your server is running out of memory it can allocate. This is a CME (Content Manager Explorer) error, not a publishing error.

As a quick "fix" you can restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ application.

As a real work-around, you may want to:

- Consider adding more memory to your server (if possible)
- Configure COM+ to recycle automatically ([google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=recycle%20com%2b))
- Check for other things running on your server that may be causing your server to run out of memory.

Comment: A lot of Thanx to Nuno. page is published by this approach. but now same problem occur in Tridion. now tridion is unable to start. it shows same problem not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Comment: Please try recycle app pool/ reset IIS. We had similar issue we tried above steps also reset/recycled app pool.
For more details refer below link
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/76/tridion-web-ui-shows-error-not-enough-storage-to-complete-this-action

Comment: i have restarted my whole system, so i think app pool should be automatically recycled.and i have added 150 kb memory to Memory Limit (KB) On the Pooling & Recycling tab, but still facing same problem.is there any thing else i should do?

Comment: +1, especially to Nuno's first and third points if on a development server or shared machine. "Other things" could be the publisher or even content delivery. Also reach out to Support. Infrastructure and configuration questions are definitely welcome, but troubleshooting a memory leak might take awhile in this Q&A format. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the issue ONLY while publishing

- Outscaling your publisher.
- You might want to consider taking a deeper look at your existing publishing process. There are some excellent articles about publishing and monitoring  [HERE](http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/04/fall-in-love-with-sdl-tridion-publishing/)  and  [HERE](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/monitoringtridionpublishingwithtridionapplicationmonitoring.aspx).

Looking at the above issue, I do not suspect it to be associated only with publishing. Do you notice this error when you perform other other CME actions (preview, edit etc.)? If you do, it indicates that you need more memory or tune COM+ ( as @Nuna suggested ).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes!!Shiva I am facing the same problem in every action in CME, I have restarted the COM+ tridion content manager application, for once page get published, but after that again same problem occurs in every action in CME.Any suggestion from ur side?

Comment: I would recommend trying the above options and also take a look at the following [thread](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/674/no-more-threads-can-be-created-in-the-system/676#676). You can contact support and they will guide you with Infrastructure issues.